# How to remove default click event from a column of datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have brought datatable's default click event on every first column by disabling responsive display's type `//type: 'none',`. Now, for some targeted action, I want to disable those click event from the first columns.

So, I have written this:

```
$('td:first-child').off('click');
```

But, click event hasn't been stopped. How to do this? [Here is my demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/OJLzWmj).

Comment: preventDefault ..................

Comment: I wish comments could be downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin does not seem to attach individual click handlers. Rather there is a global handler on `tbody` and all the logic is within. So the whole thing becomes a double-edged sword. You can achieve what you want using this:

```
$('tbody').off('click.dtr mousedown.dtr mouseup.dtr');
```

However, you should keep in mind a few things:

1. There might be some undesired side-effect to this. I do not know how exactly this large handler works so in order to figure this out you should check the code out (which is where I found the correct events and their namespaces): download the non-minified code with the Response extension, find the `_detailsInit()` function and read through it - that should be a good enough *start*.
2. There are probably some keyboard handlers as well, and depending on what you are doing you might want to take care of those too.